# Download soundcloud tracks from Ionic 2

Tags: cordova, angular, ionic2, soundcloud, file-transfer

I'm trying to download audios in my Ionic 2 app, but there is a problem. When I press the download button, I don't see anything. So if I go to the app folder I can see an audio file but it's broken because always have an 600bytes size, and I can't manually play it.

I wanted to see the progress, so after research I found to do that whit an event. So I've tried to show the progress temporaly with toast notifications, but it shows me numbers starting in "97".."98"... and then no more is happening. If I go to the app folder with my explorer, I can see the broken file. And it's no showing errors! This is the code:

```
public download(audio: any): void {

        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            console.log("Clicked to download: " + audio.id);

            let url = `https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/${audio.id}/download?client_id=${this.SC_CLIENT_ID}`;

            let pathToSaveTo: string = '';

            if (this.platform.is('android')) {
                pathToSaveTo = cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory + audio.id + '.wav';

                let fileTransfer = new Transfer();

                fileTransfer.onProgress(this.onProgress);

                fileTransfer.download(url, pathToSaveTo)
                    .then((entry) => {
                        console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
                    }, (error) => {

                        let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
                            title: 'Error',
                            subTitle: error,
                            buttons: ['Accept']
                        });

                        prompt.present();
                    });
            }


        });

    }

    onProgress = (progressEvent: ProgressEvent) : void => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
            if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {

                let progress: any = Math.round((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100);
                console.log(progress);

                let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
                  message: progress,
                  duration: 100
                });
                toast.present();

            }
        });
    }
```

Thank's so much in advance.

Ivan.